# How to disabled button until form fields isn't changed?

Tags: angular

I want to disabled submit button until the user changes any fields.
I have tried this:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Update Profile" [disabled]="!updateForm.dirty || !updateForm.touched">
```

Please help...

Comment: And in what specific scenario is it not working?

Comment: @SiddAjmera until the user doesn't change any field value

Comment: I actually tried this on a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6tqhgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) and it seems to work just fine for me. Do you mind forking mine to replicate your issue in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Update Profile" [disabled]="!updateForm.valid">
```

Try this hope it works!